# How to prevent charts or tables to disappear when I re-open Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I use Pandas with Jupyter notebook a lot. After I ingest a table in from using pandas.read_sql, I would preview it by doing the following:

`data = pandas.read_sql("""blah""")
 data`

One problem that I have been running into is that all my preview tables will disappear if I reopen my .ipynb

Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly saving your notebook before you re-open it? A Jupyter notebook is really just a large json object, eventually rendered as a fancy html object. If you save the notebook, illustrations and diagrams should be saved as well. If that doesn't do the trick, try putting the one-liner "data" in a different cell than read_sql().